# XML data for tests

Tags: xml, xpath, dataset

I searched Google and various forums for large XML files but apart from DBLP which is 1.0 GB and too-big for my needs, haven't found anything. I need sets of 30-50 MB, 100-300 MB and something like 500 MB. Does anyone know any?

p.s. Don't propose data generators since I need real data in order to use in testing with meaningful queries.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download ?

Comment: What exactly do need it for? If you are writing a business application you would need to have application-specific data instead of arbitrary data from somewhere in the internet. Therefore, if you take any XML file found on the net, I do not see any reason what keeps you from implementing your own data generator...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found good datasets. They are on:
http://dumps.wikimedia.org/mirrors.html
These are datasets from various wikis, including wikipedia. One may find various size datasets from 10MB to 500-600MB.

Answer (score 3):

You can download the entire [openstreetmap database](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm) as a 250GB xml.  That should be large enough for testing.

Comment: I need the sizes that I mentioned in the question. Please read it carefully.

Comment: why is the title of your question *Large* XML datasets then?

Comment: Those sizes are not really large. But you can also download the openstreetmap files for smaller areas. (e.g. Luxembourg which is 17M compressed, or Australia which is 215M compressed(?), ... )

Answer (score 0):

You can always generate an XML document of any size using XSLT.

Here is one well-known XML document instance (44GB, 3.8GB compressed) -- **[CityGml file](ftp://ftp.fpk.tu-berlin.de/pub/Kolbe/22x22xTestEttenheim_inkl_4xLod4Buildings.zip)**.

Comment: I don't need such big files. Just small ones.

Comment: why is the title of your question **Large** XML datasets then?

Comment: @RustamAliyev, "is not small" isn't the same as "Large". Also, you contradict yourself with your first comment that says "I don't need such big files. Just small ones". Also, the term "datasets" is confusing and misleading. I think you actually mean: "XML documents".

Comment: Sorry with that. I will change the description.